# I have an Access database, when adding other text boxes I get a connection error

Tags: c#, ms-access

Adding information to a Access data base worked well with 2 textboxes the "Name" and "Phone" when I add other textbox to the database, I get a connection error

> An unhandled exception of type'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

I get this error when inserting new data. The datagrid shows the new fields added, I can read the data I just cant add.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        con.Open();

        OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into table1 values('"+txtName.Text+"','"+txtPhone.Text+"','"+txtClockNumber.Text+"','"+txtCostCenter.Text+"')";

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();

        txtName.Text = "";
        txtPhone.Text = "";
        txtClockNumber.Text = "";
        txtCostCenter.Text = "";

        MessageBox.Show("record inserted successfully");
}
```

Comment: Do you set all values of the table1 columns?

Comment: Why don't you have ".text' for the two new fields in your "cmd.CommandText" statement?

Comment: Yes all columns have a value, I add text to the new fields still error

Comment: Learn to use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mistake in your query as  @WayneG.Dunn have mentioned

This:

```
"insert into table1 values('"+txtName.Text+"','"+txtPhone.Text+"','"+txtClockNumber+"','"+txtCostCenter+"')"
```

Must be:

```
"insert into table1 values('"+txtName.Text+"','"+txtPhone.Text+"','"+txtClockNumber.Text+"','"+txtCostCenter.Text+"')"
```

Also here is part of the article about how to insert values in MS Access.
To add one record to a table, you must use the field list to define which fields to put the data in, and then you must supply the data itself in a value list. To define the value list, use the VALUES clause.

For example, the following statement will insert the values "1", "Kelly", and "Jill" into the CustomerID, Last Name, and First Name fields, respectively.

> INSERT INTO tblCustomers (CustomerID, [Last Name], [First Name])
>       VALUES (1, 'Kelly', 'Jill')

**You can omit the field list, but only if you supply all the values that record can contain.**

> INSERT INTO tblCustomers
>       VALUES (1, Kelly, 'Jill', '555-1040', 'someone@microsoft.com')

Source [MSDN How to: Insert, Update, and Delete Records From a Table Using Access SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243852(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: This is my first Access database adding and editing columns I thought would e simple. Stumped